Excel Power Query: Force import decimal data as Text
I am importing data from an excel table into Excel power query. The excel table has decimal data but formatted as Text.
When I import this table into Excel Power Query, it reads the decimal data and adds more digits to its end. For instance, the number 1.1 in excel is converted to 1.1000000000000001. Note that not all the numbers are imported in that form. For instance, the number 2.1 is imported as it is.
Moreover, when I convert this column type to decimal number in the Power Query editor the numbers appear to be in the correct form. However, I want this column type to be Text not Decimal so I can Merge this query with another query with the correct number form.
Please refer to the following screenshots:
The data in Excel Table:

The data in Power Query Editor:

In Power Query when changing the data type to decimal:


Transform the column using Text.AfterDelimiter for a decimal with 2 characters    Or instead convert to decimal and back to text

Those values appear to be the result of some calculation. In Excel, how did you convert them to text? Note that just changing the format, which is what you seem to be showing, does not change the data type from number to text.

@horseyride converting the numbers to decimal and then back to text doesn't work, the result still appears in the same disturbed form.

@RonRosenfeld Those values are not the result of calculations, those values are entered manually one by one.
If changing the format doesn't change the data type to text so what can change it to text please?

@AliZ.ece You must format the cell as text before entering the number.

@AliZ.ece And also, I cannot reproduce your problem. If I manually type in either the number 1.1 or the same as text, I do not get the result you show. Rather I get 1.1 in Power Query Editor.

@RonRosenfeld I think you should change the type of the column to text in power query editor.
Thank you for your help though.

@AliZ.ece That is one of the ways I tested it. I could not reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.

select that column and try to use text to column function and select Text in the step 3 to transfer the data type to text.
Then import to power query to see if the data display correctly or not.


Converting to text each time a new value is inserted and ensuring that the values are converted to text is not the optimal solution in my case, thank you though for your answer.

then the next choice is to convert to Text in powerquery and exact the first 3 letters
